# Context sensitive menu in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

If I use eclipse and right click on a part of Java source code, the context menu depends on the syntactic element the user clicks on (like: a method, a variable,...).

How can I implement this kind of behaviour in my own eclipse plugin, e.g. add an item to the context menu only if the user clicks on a method in Java source code. Furthermore, the plugin needs to know which method the user clicks on.

I guess I have to relate the clicking position to the abstract syntax tree that eclipse builds but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You do this with [Eclipse Commands](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework) and you can enable them and change their visibility in many ways, depending on selection, global state, etc.

> I guess I have to relate the clicking position to the abstract syntax
>   tree that eclipse builds but I have no idea how to do that.

The good news is you (generally) don't have to do that, Eclipse has done all that heavy lifting for you.

It is quite a broad subject, so I suggest working through some tutorials on Commands first:

1. [Adding menus, toolbar and popup menus to the Eclipse IDE - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html)
2. [Eclipse Commands Advanced - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html)